# SPARQL-query (RDFlib 6.1.1) with NOT EXIST or BIND produce ParseException

Tags: sparql, rdflib

Neither (NOT) EXIST nor BIND works with RDFlib 6.1.1 and Python 3.10.

BIND - Example:

```
SELECT ?Column ?PK1 
WHERE {
?Column rdf:type dimd:PrimaryKey ;
        dimd:isPrimaryKey ?PK1 .
BIND( ?PK1 AS true ) 
}
```

EXIST - Example:

```
SELECT ?Column ?PK1 
WHERE {
?Column rdf:type dimd:PrimaryKey .
EXIST ( ?Column rdf:type dimd:PrimaryKey )
}
```

I always get a ParseException. Does I have to install an additional plugin to get it work?

Many thanks

Comment: `BIND( ?PK1 AS true ) ` - that's wrong direction. You want to bind "something" to a variable not vice versa

Comment: `EXIST ( ?Column rdf:type dimd:PrimaryKey )` - first of all it is called `EXISTS`, i.e. with a trailing `S`. Then, this is only a filter expression, i.e. you have to use it in a filter. The 3rd issue, it comprises a BGP, i.e. the brackets have to be curly brackets.

Comment: I suggest to have a look at the specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-filter-exists and https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#bind

Comment: I also don't understand why you not just use the boolean literal in the triple pattern, i.e. `dimd:isPrimaryKey true .`

Comment: Many thanks:
- BIND issue, of course and the syntax makes sense but is sensless in this case

Comment: Many thanks:
- The syntax makes sense but the usage would be senseless in this case
- Trailing S: Stupid typo
- The hint that it could be only used in FILTER and the curly brackets solved the issue. 
- The LINK was extremely helpful. I have not found the link before. 
- I have added the triple :isPrimary only because the EXISTS was not running. I will remove this statement from the ttl-file.